# Passing Multiple Parameter Values in NodeJS via Request Module

Tags: node.js, request, http-post

I am using the `request` module to make API calls. I am stuck on a particular POST method call of the SiteLeaf API - [`POST /v1/sites.json`](https://github.com/siteleaf/siteleaf-api#post-v1sitesjson).

I cant wrap my head around how all the parameters can be sent in the `POST` request.  More importantly, how I can send arbitrary key-value pairs in the `meta` parameter of the API.

**Update:**

```
var param = {};
param.title = "USER SUPPLIED TITLE";
param.domain = "USER SUPPLIED DOMAIN";
// CAUSES PROBLEM
// param.meta = {
//     baz : "foo"
// };

request({
    url: endpoint,
    method: "POST",
    qs: param
}, function(err, res, body) {
    // logic
});
```

Comment: Please show the code you have so far.

Comment: You can't (or at least shouldn't) send arbitrary key-value pairs in a single querystring parameter, you should POST a json document instead

Comment: @Jordan Updated to show the code. Without the metadata, the code runs like a charm

Comment: @Plato That is *the* cause of problem for me. Sans that, code is simple. :)

Comment: First off, the docs you  linked expect meta to be an ARRAY, not an object. Also, try sending a JSON body instead of query string params. (just a guess, their docs suck.) `curl -vX POST http://domain.tld/v1/sites.json -d "{\"baz\":\"foo\",\"meta\":{\"baz\":\"foo\"}}" -H "content-type: application/json"`